# users can login to mediawiki from another site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mediawiki, wiki

We have a asp.net MVC site. We want our users can log in to MediaWiki by their user name and password without sign up for MediaWiki. How can we do that?

This is exactly what we want:

1. our users go to the Media Wiki login form (they have no account in Media Wiki).
2. they fill the username and password input by their username and password(the username and password which they use to login to our website).
3. the username and password have to be sent to our website API link:

```
ourSiteDomain.com/Api/GetPersonRow?UserName=$userName&Password=$password
```

> The $username and $password are filled in step 2.

4. Our API returns a JSON response with user info without password.
5. if the user is really our user and API response returns true, the user can log in to Media Wiki.

These steps are what we want.

I don't know how to do these steps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a [PrimaryAuthenticationProvider](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#PrimaryAuthenticationProvider). [XenForoAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:XenForoAuth) and [IPBAuthLogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:IPBAuthLogin) are some examples.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what is your opinion to use PluggableAuth and SimpleSAMLphp extensions?  I understand the process of my work but MediaWiki makes me a little confused

Comment: PluggableAuth is a framework of sorts that makes it easier to write MediaWiki authentication providers. I think it's a good idea to use it, the raw PrimaryAuthenticationProvider interface is a bit more powerful but not intuitive.

Comment: SimpleSAML doesn't really help you since the system you trying to outsource authentication to is not a SAML server.